# Table td width fixed to th

Tags: css, datatable, fetch

I am fetching data with ajax in PHP. my table td width is not fixing to table th width. How can I manage td width in CSS.

**This is the script**

*HTML*

```
<table id="example" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th width="20%">Name</th>
        <th width="20%">Father Name</th>
        <th width="60%">Notes</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

*JS*

```
var mainTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  'ajax': 'fetch.php',
    'order': []
});
```

*PHP*

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$query = "SELECT name, fname, notes FROM lab_examinations";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$result = array('data' => array());
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ) ) {
        $name = $row->name;
        $fname = $row->fname;
        $notes = $row->notes;
    $result['data'][] = array($name, $fname, $notes);   
 }
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with CSS like this

**CSS**

```
table tbody tr{
width: auto;
}
```